# Checking DataTable for Duplicate Rows (with a twist)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

There are plenty of examples on how to check for duplicates in a DataTable, but can't find anything on how to achieve it when there is a hidden identity column in the DataGridView.
So I have a DataGridView whose DataSource comes from a SQL query. That query returns three columns, the unique identifier, plus the data required for the grid. When saving the data back, I need the identity column, but want to be able to check records for duplicates before saving, which doesn't work at present because the identity makes each row unique. There is also a 'Delete' column, so a record look like this:
[image: Example Grid]

Here is the code I'm using to check for duplicates:

```
        // Create a copy of the data
        var duplicateTable = dataTable.Clone();
        var primaryKey = new DataColumn[duplicateTable.Columns.Count];
        duplicateTable.Columns.CopyTo(primaryKey, 0);
        duplicateTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKey;
        // Check if any data row has a duplicate
        return dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(dataRow => duplicateTable.Rows.Contains(dataRow.ItemArray));
```

What I'm looking to do is check the two columns Item and Start Date to see if any of these are duplicate.

Thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: Why are you creating a copy of the table then checking for duplicates?  Of course there will be duplicates if you copy the data from one table to another (it will all be duplicated, won't it?).  It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies if that wasn't clear - what I am trying to do is to find if any duplicate rows exist in the datatable before the data is saved. I've come up with a part solution, but am unable to add the primary key in because the test data isn't unique (as it now contains duplicates).

Comment: `// Create a copy of the data for only the two specific columns    
var dataColumns = dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ItemValue", "EffectiveDate");    
var duplicateTable = dataColumns.Copy();    
var primaryKey = new DataColumn[duplicateTable.Columns.Count];
duplicateTable.Columns.CopyTo(primaryKey, 0);    
duplicateTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKey;    
// Check if any data row has a duplicate    
return dataColumns.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(dr => duplicateTable.Rows.Contains(dr.ItemArray));`

Comment: In the example grid, I'm adding a duplicate row, i.e. 38 with a Start Date of 03/07/2017, and want to return that there is a duplicate row in the data before attempting to save. Does that make sense? Also, I realised I was cloning the table so it had no data in it! I'm now copying the data and structure to the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Working through the issue, and with help from Google, I put together an approach that does what I wanted it to do - please see below.
Many thanks
Martin

```
        private static bool HasDuplicates(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            var blnReturnValue = false;
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0) goto SkipPoint;
            var dataColumns = new List<ProfessionalData>();
            for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var professionalRecord = new ProfessionalData
                {
                    ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i]["ItemId"]),
                    ItemValue = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i]["ItemValue"]),
                    EffectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataTable.Rows[i]["EffectiveDate"].ToString())
                };
                dataColumns.Add(professionalRecord);
            }

            dataColumns.ForEach(k =>
            {
                var item = dataColumns.FirstOrDefault(l =>
                    l.ItemValue == k.ItemValue && l.EffectiveDate == k.EffectiveDate);
                if (item != null) blnReturnValue = true;
            });

            SkipPoint:
            return blnReturnValue;
        }

        internal class ProfessionalData
        {
            internal int ItemId { get; set; }
            internal int ItemValue { get; set; }
            internal DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        }
```